# Example of a locally compact metric space whose completion is not locally compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Can someone suggest an example of a locally compact metric space whose completion is not locally compact?

Answer (score 2):

here it is one:
Put your self in $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$.For every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ consider the family $I_m=\{\frac{1}{m}(1+\frac{1}{i})(e_n), i,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Consider $X=\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}}I_m$. Now $\frac{1}{m} e_i \in \bar{X}, \forall m,i \in \mathbb{N}$. So $0 \in \bar{X}$. But now in every ball centered in 0, there's the sequence $\{\frac{1}{m}e_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ for $m$ big enough, and this sequence is of points with pairwise distance greater than a costant, so no Cauchy subsequence. And of course $X$ is locally compact being locally discrete(if this sounds to you too degenerate, observe that there's enough freedom to subsitute points in the definition of $I_m$ with any compact small enough shape centered in $\frac{1}{m}(1+\frac{1}{i}(e_n)$).

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Can we have an example in which the set of points of non-local compactness in the completion is not compact? Like in the above example, I think O is the only point of non-local compactness.

Comment: You are welcome. For your question: yes indeed if you consider $X+e_n$ is a set where $e_n$ is the only point of non local compactness. So consider $Y=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X+e_n$. So the set of points of non local compactness is $\{e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ wich is non compact.

Comment: Sir, I need the set in the completion, in your example I am not getting where is the completion. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry my comment was correct in the idea but i messed up the indices and so the example. Take my answer above and change all the indices of $e_n$ doubling them $n \to 2n$. Call X this space. Now consider $X+e_{2n+1}$: of course $e_{2n+1}$ is the only point of non local compactness. So consider $Y=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}X+e_{2n+1}$. This is still locally discrete so locally compact. Now the set of non compactness points contains $\{e_{2n+1}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, that has no cauchy subsequence, and you're done

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir.

Comment: You're welcome!